# ¿Cómo imprimir distintas columnas con ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, rest

Estoy creando una tabla a partir de los datos que me retorna un servicio, esto en la ruta vreporte/1 (El 1 varia dependiendo del reporte).

Desde el servicio 1 ( vreporte/1 ) llegan datos así:

```
{teatro: "Unico", graph: 24696, box: 150100}
```

Pero desde el servicio 2 (vreporte/2) llegan así.

```
{teatro: "Unico", graph: 24696, *valtarj*: 150100}
```

Y desde el servicio 3 (vreporte/3) así

```
{teatro: "Unico", graph: 24696, oxs: 150100, pkl: 432 }
```

**El problema está en que la tabla solo me está imprimiendo los datos para el primer tipo de reporte** debido a que en el ng-repeat tengo especificados los nombres de las llaves.

```
    <div class="row header">
      <div class="col" ng-repeat="titulo in titulosTabla">{{titulo | capitalize}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="dato in tabla | filter:q | orderBy:'box':true">
      <div class="col">{{dato.teatro}}</div>
      <div class="col">{{dato.graph | number:0}}</div>
      <div class="col">{{dato.box | number:0}}</div>
    </div>
```

Tabla del reporte uno

[image: tabla reporte uno]

Tabla del reporte dos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La idea es que en la misma ruta pueda hacer las tablas de todos los reportes.**

Hay forma de hacer mas flexible la tabla o el ng-repeat de tal manera que acepte otros nombres de las columnas y/o nuevas columnas??

Comment: Disculpa, la información llega por un solo servicio API, o son objetos que tienes en un factory o service?

Comment: La informacion llega desde un solo API de .net que consumo a través de POST @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Comment: Llega toda la información al mismo tiempo, o dependiendo algún filtro o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Cuando estoy en la ruta vreporte/1 llega toda la información correspondiente a ese reporte al pasar a vreporte/2 nuevamente se ejecuta la llamada al api que trae los datos correspondientes al reporte 2, no pasa por ningún filtro la agrego directo a objeto que se recorre en el ng-repeat @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solucion convirtiendo los datos que trae del servicio en una matriz y recorriendolos con dos ng-repeat anidados, de esa forma no importa el número de columnas ni los nombres, y para la cabecera de la tabla simplemente use Object.keys en el JSON que responde el servicio. Quedó así:

Tabla

```
<div class="row" id="cuerpotabla" ng-repeat="filas in tabla">
   <div class="col" ng-repeat="dato in filas">{{dato | formato}}</div>              
</div>
```

Controlador de vreporte/*

```
angular.forEach(datos,function(valor,llave){
   //datos de la grafica
   $scope.labels.push(valor.teatro);
   $scope.data.push(valor.graph);

   //datos de la tabla
   $scope.titulosTabla = Object.keys(valor);                    
   $scope.tabla.push(Object.values(valor));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Una de las mejores caracteristicas del AngularJS es que cuenta con varias directivas para manipular condicionalmente el DOM como `ng-if`, `ng-switch` y `ng-show`. Tu puedes usar cualquiera de esas para que tus datos se muestren **si existen**, así que da igual cual sea la estructura de datos estos se mostrarán correctamente.

Solo necesitas algo como esto

```
<div class="row header">
  <div class="col" ng-repeat="titulo in titulosTabla">{{titulo | capitalize}}</div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="dato in tabla | filter:q | orderBy:'box':true">
  <div class="col">{{dato.teatro}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{dato.graph | number:0}}</div>

  <div class="col" ng-if="dato.box">{{dato.box | number:0}}</div>
  <div class="col" ng-if="dato.valtarj">{{dato.valtarj | number:0}}</div>
  <div class="col" ng-if="dato.osx">{{dato.osx | number:0}}</div>
  <div class="col" ng-if="dato.pkl">{{dato.pkl| number:0}}</div>

</div>
```

Ten en cuenta que de esta forma si alguno de los datos viene en `0` tampoco se mostrará, ya que `0` es interpretado como `false`, por lo que puedes usar una condición como la siguente `ng-if="dato.box || dato.box === 0"` para solventar dicho problema.

Answer (score 0):

Existen dos caminos, desde mi perspectiva:

1- Recibir desde los servicios `vreporte/*` un identificador que te permita saber que tabla se va a procesar y así poder tener a `ng-repeat` listo con los nombres que correspondan según el servicio.

2- Utilizar la siguiente idea:

```
 <div class="col">{{dato.[0]}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{dato.[1] | number:0}}</div>
  <div class="col">{{dato.[2] | number:0}}</div>
```

De esa manera, no creas una dependencia de nombres y en consecuencia la directiva `ng-repeat` estará lista para procesar la información.